# Numbering in R based on a column value

Tags: r, dataframe

```
Name Grade
John   C
John   C+
John   C
John   B
John   A
John   A+
Kat    B
Kat    C
Kat    B
```

I want to add a new column, `Months` , starting from 3 and then continue with its multiples. The rows are all sorted. The output would look something like

```
Name Grade Months
John   C     3
John   C+    6
John   C     9
John   B     12
John   A     15
John   A+    18
Kat    B     3
Kat    C     6
Kat    B     9
```

**Rcode**

```
name <- df$Name[1]
count <- 0
for (i in 1:length(df[,1])){
    if (name!=df$Name[i]){
        count <- 0
        name <- df$Name[i]
     }
    df$Months[i] <- count
    count <- count + 3
}
```

Can I do it without a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(Months=3*seq(n()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do a cumulative sum on a vector of 3 grouped by `Name`:

```
with(df, ave(rep(3, length(Name)), Name, FUN = cumsum))
# [1]  3  6  9 12 15 18  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Name', assign (`:=`) the product of 3 with sequence of rows to 'Months'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Months := 3* seq_len(.N) , by = Name]
df1
#   Name Grade Months
#1: John     C      3
#2: John    C+      6
#3: John     C      9
#4: John     B     12
#5: John     A     15
#6: John    A+     18
#7:  Kat     B      3
#8:  Kat     C      6
#9:  Kat     B      9
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, very similar to Psidom's answer, using `seq` with `ave`, and `1:nrow(df)` instead of `df$Name`to avoid a character vector as an output.

```
ave(1:nrow(df), df$Name, FUN = seq)*3
# [1]  3  6  9 12 15 18  3  6  9
```